# Equation of circle though points of intersection of conics

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

[image]

[image]

The possible solution as per hint offered in my textbook is:

[image]

Hence the final equation of circle would be 13x²+13y²+18x+8y-59=0.

But I cannot figure out why the slope of line UV should be 1.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca P(-2,0), Q(0,-2), M(-1,0), N(0,-1) are almost readily available in the question data itself. My query is whether it relates to some general result that "a circle formed with chord of contact as a diameter will intersect the ellipse at two points such that the line passing through them is perpendicular to the chord of contact".

Comment: No, that's false, in general, as you can easily check with GeoGebra.

Comment: I think the reasoning they did is the following. The slope of line $UV$ has to be $1$, otherwise the equation of the pencil of conics would contain a $xy$ term and wouldn't be a circle. But that's a questionable argument, in my opinion.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please note that text in images should be avoided, as it can't be searched or read by visitors requiring screen readers. See [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409) for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax. ... Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple sketch reveals that the tangent points are $(-2, 0)$ and $(0, -2)$, hence $M, N$ are $(-1,0)$ and $(0, -1)$, and the line $MN$ has the equation $ x + y = -1 $.  Intersecting this line with the given ellipse, results in a quadartic equation in $x$

$ \dfrac{x^2}{9} + \dfrac{(x + 1)^2}{4} = 1 $

Multiply through by $36$

$ 4 x^2 + 9 (x + 1)^2 = 36 $

which leads to

$ 13 x^2 + 18 x - 27 = 0 $

which has the following roots

$x = \dfrac{ - 9 \pm 12 \sqrt{3} }{13} $

Hence, the center of the circle $RS$ is at

$ C = ( - \dfrac{9}{13}, -\dfrac{4}{13} ) $

The radius is $ \sqrt{2} \times \dfrac{12 \sqrt{3}}{13} = \dfrac{12 \sqrt{6}}{13} $

Therefore, the equation of the circle containing $R, S, U, V$ is

$( x + \dfrac{9}{13} )^2 + (y + \dfrac{4}{13})^2 = \left(\dfrac{12}{13}\right)^2 \times 6 $

Multiplying through by $(13)^2$

$ (13 x + 9)^2 + ( 13 y + 4 )^2 = 864 $